# How can I generate a random number every x amount of months?

Tags: php

Starting with the number 9 and using php, I would like to be able to count up from there, and echo out the next number in increments of 1. 
So, number 9, then after 1 month the number would change to 10, then another month 11, then 12 etc., with no maximum number/stop point.

How can I accomplish this? So far I have the below code.

```
$number = 9;
$output = $number + 1;

echo $output;
```

Is there a way to set this to increase once a month?

Comment: Use the `date()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)-function. This is one example of doing it if you are not dependent on the day of the month, but adding day functionality is possible and should be quit easy.

```
$startNumber = 9;

$startYear = 2015;
$startMonth = 9;

$currentYear = intval( date( "Y" ) );
$currentMonth = intval( date( "n" ) );

$monthsToAdd = ( ( $currentYear - $startYear ) * 12 )
             + ( $currentMonth - $startMonth );

echo $startNumber + $monthsToAdd;
```

Comment: Would the number reset ever based on a user refreshing their browser?

Comment: No, the number is allways calculated the same depending on which start year/month and which start number you define in this code.

So next month, all users would see "10", in two months, all users would see "11", and so on. This works "over the years", so next month in one year all users would see a 22 (9+13).

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to increase every three months?

Comment: Sure, but this is more about math than about PHP: devide $monthsToAdd through 3 before adding it to $startNumber. After three months, you get 3/3=1, after six months 6/3=2 and so on. You will have to wrap the operation  in `floor( )` - that will round the result down.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I'd say:

```
$number = 9;
$output = date('n') + $number;
echo $output;
```

But that depends on what you are trying to accomplish. You can also wrap the number around the `date()` with a modulo.

However this is nothing random. If you want to create a random number every month like your topic suggests, use the month as the random seed.

```
srand(date('n'));
$number = rand();
```

Answer (score 1):

a very inefficient way would be

```
<?php
function increm($duration){
  while ($i<$duration) {
    $i++;
  }
  return true;
}
$number = 9;
$start = time();
$i = 0;
while (1){
  increm(3600*24*30);
  $i++;
  // Do your code
}
?>
```

this script would have to be run continuously for months.

A better way would be

```
<?php
$number = 9;
if(!file_exists('date.txt')){
   $date=date('n');
   file_put_contents( (string)time());
   $date = 0;
}
else{
  $date= file_get_contents('date.txt');
  $date= date()-(int)$date;
  $date= floor($date/(24*3600*30));
}
// do whatever you may
?>
```

But this script would increase it whenever called as the first open date would be stored. Will work forever (till UNIX can timestamp).

Comment: So the bottom option would be the best solution? What is the date.txt? Would this number reset?

Comment: No. no solution is 'best' or 'worst' they are just efficient or inefficient. In the bottom one, the number would never reset. As the starting month is saved in a date.txt file (it can be anything else) as a result there will be less overhead. Though, if you think of generating random numbers @Yorick_de_Wid's solution would be better

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you have to store the number in the database, compare with current unix timestamp and update it when the new month is reached.

2 database columns: **count_month int(10)** and **next_month int(10)** where next_month will contain the unix timestamp of the first day of the next month. you can run it with cronjobs or on production.

```
<?php
$now = strtotime("now");
$next_month = strtotime("first day of next month");

if ($query = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT next_month FROM table1")) {
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($compare_time);
$query->store_result();
$row_count = $query->num_rows;
if ($row_count > 0) {
   while ($query->fetch()) {
     if ($compare_time < $now) { // you reached the 1th of the next month time to update
         if ($query2 = $dbconnect->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET count_month=count_month +1, next_month=?")) {
         $query2->bind_param('i', $next_month);
         $query2->execute();
         $query2->close();
         }
     }
   }
}

$query->free_result();
$query->close();
}
?>
```